# Git REPO CRLF vs local line end

Tags: git

I am working with a repo which has a few .C and .H files *in the repo itself* using CRLF, while the rest appear to be using standard LF.  Because of this, the 'auto' conversion (which I presume expects all text files to be LF) doesn't touch them.  This results in those files being modified with what seems like CRLF churn.

If my understanding is right, this is because GIT expects working tree to be LF, because it expects repo files to be LF and it didn't initiate any conversion it was aware of, therefore the CRLF looks modified.

If all of that appears sound, then my question is - **is there a way to configure GIT so that it *will* convert on checkout/commit those CRLF-repo'd files?**  In this specific instance it's on a mac, so I'd be going:

```
repo CRLF -> working LF
edit LF-file
checkin, going
working LF -> repo CRLF
```

Fixing the original CRLF -> LF is probably better but I do not control the repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not *quite* right, but close enough:  The issue here is that Git has what amounts to *directional conversion*.  The Git documentation does not talk about its conversions this way, but maybe it should.

It may help to think of files stored in Git as being in "Git format": compressed and, if you define a *clean filter* via `.gitattributes` and your configuration, *cleaned*.  Even if you don't define a specific clean filter, if you set up CRLF conversions, Git performs some cleaning here: the files stored in the repository will be LF-only.  Files in your work-tree, as you almost said, are expected to be in your preferred working format: not Git-compressed, using CRLF endings *if* you selected them, and *smudged* via your *smudge filter* if you set one of those up (similar to setting up a clean filter).

This is really mostly for Windows users, where Windows editors and environments have some sort of preference for CRLF line endings.  When this is all set up correctly, the working copies of files, which one uses when working, have CRLF endings the way Windows wants, and committed copies of files, which can only be used by checking them out into working copies, have LF-only endings the way Linux prefers them.

These transformations are actually performed at the time that files move from the *index*—the intermediate structure that Git imposes between commits and work-trees—to the work-tree, or from the work-tree to the index.  Git makes commits from whatever is in the index, so by "cleaning" files on their way from work-tree to index, Git can commit the clean versions, and by dirtying files on their way from index to work-tree, Git can provide the dirty CRLF endings that Windows likes.

We can turn this kind of conversion on or off.  When it's *all* turned *all the way* off, Git does not bother to *check* anything, so that files in the index are purely just compressed versions of files in the work-tree, and files in the work-tree are purely just uncompressed versions of whatever is in the index (until you modify the work-tree version yourself of course).  In this case, you can get CRLF endings into the repository.  This seems to be what has happened with your particular repository.

The simplest approach to dealing with this, on any system where CRLF does not hurt usability (which is most systems), is to just leave it.  The next-simplest is to fix it *in the repo*, but as you said, that requires having control of the repository.

If some particular file is giving you problems because of its CRLF endings, there's nothing built into Git that will translate it to LF-only in your work-tree, then back to CRLF when you `git add` the result.  You can, however, set up your own smudge and clean filters that do exactly that: have the smudge filter *clean* the file (by turning CRLF into LF-only), and have the clean filter *dirty* the file (by turning LF-only into CRLF).  You can then set up a `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` file to *use* these filters on the specific files.  See [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for more details, but essentially:

```
badfile1.ext    filter=reverse-clean
badfile2.xtn    filter=reverse-clean
```

along with:

```
[filter "reverse-clean"]
    clean = sed -e $'s/\\r*$/\\r/'
    smudge = sed -e $'s/\\r$//'
```

(now tested as a Git filter driver—the above assumes the command is fed to `sh -c` and your `sh` interprets `$'...'`; the doubled backslashes are due to the fact that this goes into a config file).

As you note in a comment below, there's a minor annoyance with `git diff` showing the carriage returns on changed lines, but not on surrounding lines, which makes the differences look a bit ugly.  It does seem to work as desired though.

Comment: This is a great answer and helped me tremendously.  Thank you!  One note is GIT wanted those sed regex's escaped.  GIT got a little fiddly in one part, it pops up ^M in the DIFF on files affected by this, but your methodology indicates any LF/CRLF wackiness is cleaned before final push anyway.